# condtionally render the content in vf pag email template in salesforce

Tags: visualforce, email-template, vf-email-template

Depending upon account type( personal, commercial) need to render welcome message in VF page with if condition.

relatedToType="Account"

for commercial account

{!relatedTo.Name},

for personal account

Dear {!relatedTo.FirstName},

how to render the given requirement with if condition in vf page.

Comment: PTAL https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AvhoIAC

Comment: what are the recordtype names for Person accounts in your org?

Answer (score 0):

IF(relatedTo.Account.isPersonAccount, 'Dear ' + relatedTo.Account.FirstName, relatedTo.Account.Name) This worked for me.Thanks